/auth/login got 403 forbidden
I'm currently create JWT configuration for my web. I have followed https://medium.com/@tericcabrel/implement-jwt-authentication-in-a-spring-boot-3-application-5839e4fd8fac and I success in the/auth/signup but not with /auth/login.
Here is my code
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {
    private final AccountRepository userRepository;
    private final UserDetailsServiceImpl accountService;

    public ApplicationConfiguration(AccountRepository userRepository, UserDetailsServiceImpl accountService) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.accountService = accountService;
    }

    @Bean
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        if (userRepository == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        }
        return userRepository::findByUsername;
    }

    @Bean
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

       authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return authProvider;
    }
}

@Slf4j
@RequestMapping("/auth")
@RestController
public class AuthenticationController {
    private final JwtService jwtService;

    private final AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    public AuthenticationController(JwtService jwtService, AuthenticationService authenticationService) {
        this.jwtService = jwtService;
        this.authenticationService = authenticationService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<Account> register(@RequestBody RegisterDto registerAccountDto) {
        Account registeredAccount = authenticationService.signup(registerAccountDto);
        log.debug("Registered account: {}", registeredAccount);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(registeredAccount);
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<LoginResponse> authenticate(@RequestBody LoginDto loginUserDto) {
        Account authenticatedUser = authenticationService.authenticate(loginUserDto);

        String jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(authenticatedUser);

        LoginResponse loginResponse = new LoginResponse().setToken(jwtToken).setExpiresIn(jwtService.getExpirationTime());
        log.debug("Login response: {}", loginResponse);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(loginResponse);

    }
}

@Service
public class AuthenticationService {
    private final AccountRepository userRepository;

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public AuthenticationService(
            AccountRepository userRepository,
            AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
            PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder
    ) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    public Account signup(RegisterDto input) {
        Account user = new Account();
        user.setUsername(input.getUsername());
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(input.getPassword()));

        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    public Account authenticate(LoginDto input) {
        try {
            System.out.println("input.getUsername() = " + input.getUsername());
            Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(input.getUsername(), input.getPassword())
            );
            // Kiểm tra nếu xác thực thành công
            if (authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
                return userRepository.findByUsername(input.getUsername());
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException("Unknown authentication error");
            }
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            // Ném ra lỗi thông tin đăng nhập sai
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid username or password", e);
        } catch (DisabledException e) {
            // Ném ra lỗi tài khoản bị vô hiệu hóa
            throw new RuntimeException("Account is disabled", e);
        } catch (LockedException e) {
            // Ném ra lỗi tài khoản bị khóa
            throw new RuntimeException("Account is locked", e);
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            // Bắt tất cả các loại lỗi xác thực khác
            throw new RuntimeException("Authentication failed", e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Bắt tất cả các loại lỗi khác
            throw new RuntimeException("Unknown error", e);
        }
    }
}

I found out when I use Postman to test this app, the api got stuck at the line
Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(input.getUsername(), input.getPassword())
            );

how can I fix that?

you need to know WHY you are getting 403, set logging level to debug with logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG so that you see the error. After that paste the error into question
